# Connection Refused with nginx and kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I trying to deploy my angular application with kubernates inside a container with nginx.

I create my docker file:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci && mkdir /ng-app && mv ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist

FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx config:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;


  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;


  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass https://my-api;
  }

}
```

If I launch this image locally It works perfectly but when I deploy this container inside a kubernate cluster the site load fine but all api request shows the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I'm trying to deploy in GCP I build the image and then publish my image by GCP dashboard.

Some idea for this `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with my requests, I was using `localhost` at the URL, with that I took the wrong pod IP. I've just changed the request to use straight the service IP and that sort out my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes Engine nodes are provisioned as instances in Compute Engine. As such, they adhere to the same stateful firewall mechanism as other instances.  Have you configured the firewall rules?

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/prep-kubernetes-engine-for-prod#firewalling

Comment: Yep! I tried to follow the process to create firewall rule but the problem continue :(

Answer (score 2):

Good that you have figured out the issue. But, Did you try using the service_names instead of the Pod IPs? It is suggested method(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) of accessing services by their names within the Kubernetes cluster and with NodeIP or LoadBalancerIP outside the cluster.